# Strange fluctuating behaviour in time difference between successive frames read

Tags: matlab, video-processing

Intuitively I would assume that using the function `readFrame(videoObj)` to read each frame would change the attribute `videoObj.CurrentTime` as such:

```
videoObj.CurrentTime = videoObj.CurrentTime + videoObj.FrameRate * videoObj.Duration
```

I.e. whenever each frame is extracted from `videoObj`, `videoObj.CurrentTime` is set to the time value in the video file where the next frame is located.

However, by observing how the attribute `videoObj.CurrentTime` changes throughout the reading of the video file, I see that the above is **almost** correct. (see the bottom of this question)

So, does anyone have an idea of why the time difference between successive frames is fluctuating?

Here is the code used to plot the time difference between successive frames during reading.

```
video = VideoReader('filename');
time = zeros(video.FrameRate * video.Duration,2);
time(1,1) = video.CurrentTime;
i = 2;
while hasFrame(video)
    frame = readFrame(video);
    time(i,1) = video.CurrentTime;
    time(i,2) = time(i,1)-time(i-1,1);
    i = i + 1;
end

figure;plot(time(:,1),time(:,2),'*')
xlabel('elapsed time in the video')
ylabel('time difference between frames')
```

And here is a plot over the variable `time`, http://oi62.tinypic.com/2ykf7zm.jpg. (SO wouldn't let me upload the figure here, because I don't have enough reputation points).

If you feel uncomfortable clicking the link, here are some relevant snippets of the variable `time`. The left column is the elapsed time in the video, i.e. `videoObj.CurrentTime` during the reading, and the right column is the increase in `videoObj.CurrentTime` in each reading.

`0      0
0.0660  0.0660
0.1330  0.0670
0.2000  0.0670
0.2660  0.0660
0.3330  0.0670
0.4000  0.0670
0.4660  0.0660
0.5330  0.0670
0.6000  0.0670`

...

`1.4660 0.0660
1.5330  0.0670
1.6000  0.0670
1.7330  0.1330
1.8000  0.0670
1.8660  0.0660
1.9330  0.0670
2       0.0670`

As you can see the time difference between each reading fluctuates between 0.0660 and 0.0670. This can probably be explained by the precision of approximating floating numbers (but isn't a precision of order 10^-3 very bad anyway?). BUT, at some points, the difference is twice as much as it should be, with a value of 0.1330. I.e. it seems that `readFrame(videoObj)` skips a frame. How can I make sure that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

The equation

```
videoObj.CurrentTime = videoObj.CurrentTime + videoObj.FrameRate * videoObj.Duration
```

is valid only if the video stream has a fixed frame rate. There are numerous video files out there where the frame-rate of the video varies within the video stream. One of the reasons for doing this is improved compression (for a slowly varying scene, you can lower the frame-rate). The FrameRate reported in this case is the average frame rate.

The file you are working with could be variable frame-rate file.

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the video indeed has a varying frame rate. Thank you, Dinesh, I wasn't aware of this practice.